# From python get value from an XML file

Tags: python, xml

in Python, I'm trying to get a value from an XML file but i can't find any similar pattern in other questions.

```
<Potts>
<!-- Basic properties of CPM (GGH) algorithm -->
<Dimensions z="1" y="150" x="150"/>
<Steps>10000</Steps>
<Temperature>10</Temperature>
</Potts>
<Plugin Name="Volume">
<VolumeEnergyParameters TargetVolume="9" LambdaVolume="5" CellType="cell"/>
</Plugin>
```

I can easily get the value from steps and temperature, but I can't get the value from "LambdaVolume"

The part of my code dealing with this is

```
    tree = ET.parse(xmldoc)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for list in root.iter("Temperature"):
        Temperature_tmp = list.text

    for list in root.iter("Steps"):
        Step_tmp = list.text
```

As a reminder, I'm coding in Python and only use the XML made by another software to get initial condition from a simulation. I've never dealt with XML before so I'm quite lost with the whole parents and children thing and its syntax.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20808398/13619394). Please feel free to ask in the comments section if you have any sort of difficulties.